# Getting Data from server Continuosly

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I need to get data from server continuously. I have searched and then   I am came to a thought of calling service in background thread continuously in particular time interval using NSTimer.

```
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: "callService", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    func callService()
     {
       let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
       let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        .....

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
          ......
        })
      })
     }
```

Can we do like this?. Is this a good way to do this? Or  Is there any other way to do this? I really want to know how `didUpdateLocation`
in `CLLocationManagerDelegate` works. I want to implement similar approach like that. Please give your idea in this.

Comment: No, you can't use an nstimer from the background. You should look at background fetch or if you need more frequent updates, push messages

Comment: yeah. I did study about push messages. It will be only 256 byte, but my data may exceed this size limit. And also depend on the data from server (its like latitude and longitude of list of devices) I need to update UI. I did study on background fetch also. But mine is not this case. In NSTimer scenario, may I call service in separate thread without background thread?

Comment: I really want approach like 'didUpdateLocation' method in 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'. I want continuous update of data from server automatically. Did you have any idea how it really works.

Comment: This is not a mode that is supported on iOS. A mobile device is not a general purpose computer. It has battery and bandwidth limitations. Your options are push notifications that prompt your app to download some additional information or background fetch mode but both of these are rate limited.

Comment: okay, Thanks. I understood this has to implement in server. I doing study on anything has to do on iOS side. Thanks for your reply.  I going to study on how  'didUpdateLocation'  implemented in server. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I acheived it through socket.io. I saw this site http://geoloqi.com/blog/2011/09/building-a-real-time-location-based-urban-geofencing-game-with-socket-io-redis-node-js-and-sinatra-synchrony/#comments. When I go through that link, I could understand they did same like me using NSTimer to call a service at particular time interval. But it used great battery power. Then they used Socket.

I got socket.io code for swift 2 from github https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

```
let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "localhost:8080")

socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
    print("socket connected")
}

socket.on("currentAmount") {data, ack in
    if let cur = data[0] as? Double {
        socket.emitWithAck("canUpdate", cur)(timeoutAfter: 0) {data in
            socket.emit("update", ["amount": cur + 2.50])
        }

        ack?.with("Got your currentAmount", "dude")
    }
}

socket.connect()
```

It solved my question.